# Javascript Garbage Collection on a Returned Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sure that this is an easy question for JS experts out there. Unfortunately for me I'm not one of them.

I've got the following situation. I'm creating an array in function b that I populate with some new objects. I then return that array back to function a (which called function b).

When I iterate through the returned array, the contents are all undefined. Off the cuff I figure that the JS garbage collector is probably involved here. How would I go about fixing this?

Sincerely,

mj

```
function a()
{
    var x = b();

    for( var v in x ){
        //print out v.id and v.name
    }
}

function b()
{
    var y = new Array();
    var m = new Object();
    var n = new Object();
    m.id = 1;
    n.id = 2;
    m.name = "alpha";
    n.name = "bravo";

    y.push( m );
    y.push( n );

    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is how you are "iterating" through your array. You are using the `for-in` statement, and this statement should be used to **enumerate** object properties, not to **iterate** over arrays or array-like objects.

From your code:

```
for( var v in x ){
    //print out v.id and v.name
}
```

The `for-in` statement in every iteration will feed `v` with *the name of each property*, since you are using an array in your example, `v` will be `'0'`, `'1'`, etc.

You could access `x[v]` but I really encourage you to use a sequential `for` loop, for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  alert(x[i].id);
  alert(x[i].name);
}
```

There are many reasons why to avoid `for-in`, when your purpose is "iterate" over numeric indexes on array like objects, see the following questions for more information:

- [Loop through array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)
- [JavaScript “For …in” with Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays/4261096#4261096)

Answer (score 1):

You should not interate over an array in that way.  You are looping through all of the properties/methods of the array, etc.

You can see this if you alert `v` http://jsfiddle.net/Xk7yB/

If you use a regular for loop, it works fine:

```
function a()
{
    var x = b();

    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
         alert(x[i].name);   
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xk7yB/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can also use:

```
$.each(x,function(){
    alert(this.id);
    alert(this.name);
});
```

The jQuery `$.each()` is most similar to the `foreach` mechanism you are used to.